# Default file other than index.html

Tags: jekyll

Is there a way to have a file other thing index.html or index.md served as a folder's default file?  Specifically, I'm looking to keep my .json file extention, but have it reference-able as /api-docs/myapi/  instead of /api-docs/myapi/myapi.json.

Answer (score 3):

You can use permalink in your yaml front matter :

```
Permalink: api-doc/myapi/myapi.json
```

**Edit**: As @SAMdroid pointed it, I misunderstood the question, and as he says in is answer, it's a server configuration matter. But, it's sadly not possible to change default served page on Github Pages.

Your json can only be reached at **api-doc/myapi/myapi.json**

Comment: This worked for me, only downside is my IDE doesn't like the frontmatter in the .json file.

Comment: @theshawn wants to have it as an index file, so he would have to have it as "index.html".  But if that happened the file would be served with the wrong mine type.

Comment: from what I understood @theshawn want's to reach a json file at  /api-docs/myapi/myapi.json that will be served as application/json

Comment: @DavidJacquel "have it reference-able as **/api-docs/myapi/ instead of /api-docs/myapi/myapi.json**"

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that it changes the extension, thus changing it's mime type.  I guess there is no perfect answer here, other than serving it up as .json (which in swagger "shows" the .json extension in the UI, making it a little less attractive).  Thanks for the ideas and clarifications.

Comment: I just thought of a nice little hack to get this to work: with js you can force `XmlHTTPRequest` to pretend that you got a header (eg. One to set the mime).  Is this for your app or a public api?

Answer (score 3):

This configuration is mostly in your web server.  You can set the files for the server to look for to `index.json` (as well as `index.html` and `index.htm` which are common on most servers).  For example, this can be configured on nginx by adding this to your server block:

```
index index.json index.html index.htm;
```

If nginx gets a request for `/some/folder`, it will try to serve `/some/folder/index.json`, `/some/folder/index.html`, `/some/folder/index.htm` then your 404 page with this configuration.

Comment: I'm quite new to this, what would the web server be for Github Pages/Jekyll?

Comment: You can't do this on GitHub - you don't have control of the sever.